MariaDB Corrupted page identifier crashes randomly setting innodb_force_recovery=1 resolves it
This is the first time I've experienced this particular problem so looking for some help in resolving it.
I run a Centos 9 Stream server running MariaDB for my Laravel 11 project, a few hours ago the database went offline and I wasn't able to restart mariadb. After checking the log in /var/log/maraidb/mariadb.log it mentioned something to do with a "Corrupted page identifier" and that I should set innodb_force_recovery=1
I went ahead with this and set the following within /etc/my.cnf and ran systemctl daemon-reload
innodb_force_recovery=1

I was able to then start mariadb. I left this set to 1 for a few minutes, then tried commenting it out and restarting mariadb, and that seems to be fine?
What should I do form here? Worried that this will happen again?
Does setting innodb_force_recovery actually clear the problem?
Here's the output of the log prior to this happening:
2024-11-03  8:43:58 0 [Note] Starting MariaDB 10.11.6-MariaDB source revision fecd78b83785d5ae96f2c6ff340375be803cd299 as process 10029
2024-11-03  8:43:58 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2024-11-03  8:43:58 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of transaction pools: 1
2024-11-03  8:43:58 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using crc32 + pclmulqdq instructions
2024-11-03  8:43:58 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
2024-11-03  8:43:58 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 128.000MiB, chunk size = 2.000MiB
2024-11-03  8:43:58 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2024-11-03  8:43:58 0 [Note] InnoDB: File system buffers for log disabled (block size=512 bytes)
2024-11-03  8:43:58 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery from checkpoint LSN=3177494355512
2024-11-03  8:43:58 0 [Note] InnoDB: Multi-batch recovery needed at LSN 3177535143735
2024-11-03  8:43:58 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Corrupted page identifier at 3177544786030; set innodb_force_recovery=1 to ignore the record.
2024-11-03  8:43:58 0 [Note] InnoDB: End of log at LSN=3177544786030
2024-11-03  8:43:58 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Plugin initialization aborted with error Generic error
2024-11-03  8:43:58 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
2024-11-03  8:43:59 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
2024-11-03  8:43:59 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2024-11-03  8:43:59 0 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
2024-11-03  8:43:59 0 [ERROR] Aborting


Have you read the manual on innodb_force_recovery? It does not really fix anything. See the last section Fixing Things specifically about running mariadb-check https://mariadb.com/kb/en/innodb-recovery-modes/ Personally on my databases I have overnight scripts running check <table> and analyze <table> and optimize <table> with appropriate error checking and logging for any issues. (Note: that sort of thing might not be appropriate for large enterprise databases etc, but for my purposes it works fine.)

I ran mysqlcheck -u root -p --all-databases afterwards and all tables came back "OK", additionally, when I set innodb_force_recovery to 1, a few minutes later when i turned it off, mariadb restarted with no problems? I did read the docs yes
